# Hibernate отношение Many-to-One с использованием аннотаций

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Есть таблицы "один" и "Два". Связь между ними - "many-to-one". Необходимо сделать вставку в таблицу `Один` и таблицу `Два`. Но если в таблице `Два` уже есть запись, то в нее ничего не вставлять, а в соответствующее поле таблицы `Один`, вставить идентификатор записи из таблицы `Два`.

Нашел неплохой [пример](https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-many-to-one-using-annotations-1.html). Единственным недостатком является то, что нужная мне группировка во второй таблице, работает только в пределах одной транзакции, т.е. не учитываются данные, которые уже находятся в таблице (возможно `hibernate` тупо сравнивает их по хеш кодам, чтобы не было дублей одного объекта).

Как организовать запись в таблицы со связью `many-to-one`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По Вашей ссылке приведен вполне рабочий одноразовый пример.

Немного теории по методам `org.hibernate.Session`:

`save(Object)` — сохраняет объект в БД, **генерируя новый Id, даже если он установлен.** Object может быть в статусе `transient` или `detached`.

`update(Object)` — обновляет объект в БД, преобразуя его в `persistent` (Object в статусе `detached`).

`saveOrUpdate(Object)` — вызывает `save()` или `update()`.

Скорее всего, в Вашем приложении, несколько раз вызывается метод `save(Object)` для сохранения одной и той же сущности (хэши одинаковые и в случае каких-то ограничений в таблицах вы получите SqlExceptions). Попробуйте использовать метод `saveOrUpdate(Object)`.
При вызове `saveOrUpdate(Object)`, hibernate сам решит добавлять(insert) или обновить(update) существующую сущность в таблице.

**Дополнительная терминология для раскрытия темы.**

Объект  сущности может находиться в четырех состояниях: `transient`, `persistent`, `detached`, `removed`.

`Transient` объект создаётся командой new и может быть заполнен данными но, он  ни когда не сохранялся в сессии hibernate, т.е. не ассоциирован со строкой в таблице базы.

`Persistent` объект, это объект, в данный момент связанный с некоторой сессией hibernate. Сессия работает с экземпляром объекта в данный промежуток времени, т.е. подразумевается что объект сущности ассоциирован со строкой в таблице базы.  Получить `persistent` объект можно двумя способами, 1-й способ: запросить объект следующими методами: `get()`, `load()`, `list()`, `uniqueResult()`, `iterate()`, `scroll()`, `find()` или `getReference()`. 2-й способ: перевести наш `transient` объект сущности в `persistent` объект путем вызова таких методов как `save()`, `saveOrUpdate()`, `persist()` или `merge()`.

`Detached` объект - это `persistent` объект, отсоединенный от сессии. Это состояние объекта возникает после закрытия сессии `close()`, которая работала с объектом до этого или при вызовах методов сессии `evict()` или `clear()`.  Переход из состояния `detached` обратно в состояние `persistent` объекта сущности возможно при вызове методов сессии  `update()`, `saveOrUpdate()` или `merge()`.

`Removed` объект - это `persistent` объект сущности, удаленный в сессии методом  `delete()` или `remove()` в jpa. После применения транзакции объект будет удален из таблицы базы.

`Detached` объекты можно использовать и дальше, при работе с новой сессией. Если к ним применить такие команды как `update()`, `saveOrUpdate()` или `merge()`, то они переходят в состояние `persistent` как упоминалось выше. В Hibernate такие операции называются `reattached mode` или `merging mode` в jpa.